# MySQL error updating a table using join

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a table in a mysql database, and am getting a syntax error. It is a MyISAM table if that matters.

Here is the sql

```
UPDATE product SET price=(price*1.0909)
JOIN product_to_category ON product.product_id = product_to_category.product_id
WHERE category_id =6
OR category_id =1
OR category_id =2
```

My goal is to get a list of products from 3 specific categories (information from the *product_to_category* table) and increase the price by about 10%. The price is contained in the *product* table.

From what I see in the documentation I can use join in the update statement, and I have done similar queries in the past.

This is a production website, which currently has about 40,000 products. If needed I can do a php script that will loop through the products and do it one by one, but it seems like I should be able to do it directly from mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is a little bit messed up. `SET` follows after `JOIN` which is part of the `UPDATE` clause.

```
UPDATE product 
       JOIN product_to_category 
           ON product.product_id = product_to_category.product_id
SET    price = price * 1.0909
WHERE  category_id IN (1,2,6)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, I knew I wasn't too far off. Makes perfect sense now, but I stared at that for a long time trying to figure out where I went wrong.